# PyQt5: widget not displayed after being added to layout

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, layout, pyqt

The task is to write a robot emulator. I have three classes in my code: ControlWidget, BoardWidget and Emulator (the main widget that should combine Control and Board in one window). I'm going to draw some pictures on the BoardWidget with the use of QPainter.

```
class ControlWidget(QFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()        
        self._vbox_main = QVBoxLayout()
        self.initUI()        

    def initUI(self):
        # ... adding some buttons        
        self.setLayout(self._vbox_main)
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 600, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('Robot Controller')

class BoardWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()       
        self._robot_pixmap = QPixmap("robo.png")            
        self.initUI()            

    def initUI(self):
        self.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background: #123456 }")
        self.setFixedSize(300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("Robot Emulator")
```

Both of them appear nicely if shown in different windows:

```
class Emulator(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._control = ControlWidget()
        self._board = BoardWidget()
        self._board.show()
        self._control.show()
```

[image: That's the result...]

But the magic comes here. I want my Emulator show both the board and control:

```
class Emulator(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._control = ControlWidget()
        self._board = BoardWidget()        
        self.initUI()
        self.show()

    def initUI(self):
        layout = QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout.RightToLeft, self)
        layout.addWidget(self._control)
        layout.addStretch(1)
        layout.addWidget(self._board)
        self.setLayout(layout)        
        self.setWindowTitle('Robot Emulator')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("./assets/robo.png"))
        # self._board.update()
```

[image: And the board's background disappears...]

I've killed three hours trying to fix it. I've tried to present my board as a QPixmap over the QLabel inside the QBoxLayout. I tried to replace QBoxLayout with the QHBoxLayout. Nothing makes any difference.

Comment: You need to set a layout on the `BoardWidget` and add a widget to it (e.g. a `QLabel` showing the robot pixmap).

Answer (score 1):

As @ekhumoro stated in the comments, it is necessary to add the `QPixmap` to a `QLabel` and then set it on the `BoardWidget` layout manager with `setLayout()` function.

One solution could be the next reimplementation of `BoardWidget` class:

```
class BoardWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._robot_pixmap = QPixmap("robo.png")
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setPixmap(self._robot_pixmap)
        self._vbox_board = QVBoxLayout()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self._vbox_board.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(self._vbox_board)
        self.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background: #123456 }")
        self.setFixedSize(300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("Robot Emulator")
```

The result is shown here:

[image]